# C++ What does size_t(iterator1 - iterator2) mean?

Tags: c++

`iterator1` and `iterator2` are two pointers of a structure.

I know that `size_t(iterator1 - iterator2)` is to get the length. But how can we use `size_t` like that? Is that similar to the forced type conversion like `(size_t)(iterator1 - iterator2)`?

Comment: Although using `szie_t` for a difference doesn't make a lot of sense since you can have a negative difference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your syntax is merely an instruction to create a `size_t` based on the value of the expression `iterator1 - iterator2`.

`size_t` is not the best type for this (as it's `unsigned`), and neither is the method taken the best approach.

Assuming that `iterator1` and `iterator2` are iterators on the same container (otherwise the behaviour of what I present and what you have is undefined),

```
auto diff = std::distance(iterator1, iterator2);
```

is to be preferred.

Comment: I rather suspect that the only reason you would cast the result to a `size_t` like this is if you needed the result to be a `size_t` which would make it the best type for this. Although some test to ensure data is not corrupted would be appropriate.